# How to make Android Studio/Gradle build from an updated source file?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

In my previous Windows/Eclipse/ant project development method I had a means of producing a time-limited release apk from the command line. I would like to reproduce this functionality with my new Ubuntu/Android Studio/Gradle setup.

This is how the old system worked:

I had a .bat file which ran a runnable jar which I wrote (and can also create on my new machine). That jar takes two arguments expiry date and where to put the output file. The jar's output is called Timekey.java and it looks like:

```
package uk.co.myname.timekey;
public final class  Timekey{
   public static final String EXPIRY_DATE = 
   "the encrypted string";
   public String getExpiryDate() {
      return EXPIRY_DATE;
   }
}
//  Plain date : 2020-01-01.00_00_00
```

I have my build.xml checking for the presence of this file

```
<target name="-check-timekey">
            <echo>"${timelimit_src}/Timekey.java"</echo>
            <available file="${timelimit_src}/Timekey.java" property="timekey.present" />
</target>
```

and if present it sets the src

```
<if condition="${timekey.present}">
                    <src path="${timelimit_src}" />
```

Thus I can produce an apk which will only run up to the date entered as a parameter to the batch file. The encryption is not military grade but good enough to defeat amateurs and should stop the de-obfuscation fiends.

Any ideas on how to implement this with gradle will be most welcome. I know how to run the jar from a bash script but swapping source directories, just for command line release builds has me stumped

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to solve this in the end. I created the build type 'release' which was not previously necessary,as 'main' sufficed. I also reated the build type 'timelimited'. Timekey.java was removed from main and placed in debug, release and timelimited's src/java folders (including the class stucture hierarchical folders).

This script completed the process

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script to build time limited apk NBT 2nd March 2016
# Must be run from one leve below AndroidStudioProjects folder
# Must have one argument of expiry date in YYYY-MM-DD format

CURRENT_DIR=`pwd`

case "$CURRENT_DIR" in
  *AndroidStudioProjects/*) ;;
  *)   echo "Quitting because  of wrong starting directory name"
       echo "You must be one folder below ~/AndroidStudioProjects to run this script"
       exit 1 ;;
esac

OUTDIR_SUFFIX=/app/src/timelimited/java/uk/co/myname/timekey/
OUTDIR=$CURRENT_DIR$OUTDIR_SUFFIX

echo "Directory to write in: "$OUTDIR

if [ -z "$1" ] 
then
   echo "argument 1 required, as expiry date in YYYY-MM-DD format, so quitting"
   exit 1
fi
EXDATE=$1

case "$EXDATE" in
  ????-??-??) ;;
   *)   echo "Quitting because of bad date format on parameter 1"
       exit 1 ;;
esac
# the encrypt5.jar requires these two arguments
java -jar ~/runnablejars/encrypt5.jar $EXDATE $OUTDIR
echo " "
echo " "
gradlew assembleTimelimited

cat $OUTDIR/Timekey.java
echo " "

echo "All done, now IF you saw Timekey.java printed out, then"
echo "the time limited apk is built. Run gradlew InstallTimelimited"
echo "to install it on a running device"

while true; do
    read -p "Do you wish to install this apk on running device y/n [enter]? " yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) gradlew InstallTimelimited; break;;
        [Nn]* ) exit;;
        * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
    esac
done
```

I hope this might prove useful. There are probably less convoluted ways of doing it but I don't know one.